# Converted JavaScript to FBJS - tabs still not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, tabs, fbml, fbjs

I tried my best to convert JavaScript to FBJS according to this page: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS.

Yet my tabs are still not working properly. Does anyone have any suggestions how to fix this so I can click through the tabs and display and hide content accordingly:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var tabLinks = [];
var contentDivs = [];

function init() {

  var tabListItems = document.getElementById('tabs').getChildNodes();
  for ( var i = 0; i < tabListItems.length; i++ ) {
    if ( tabListItems[i].getNodeName("LI") ) {
      var tabLink = getFirstChildWithTagName( tabListItems[i], 'A' );
      var id = getHash( tabLink.getAttribute('href') );
      tabLinks[id] = tabLink;
      contentDivs[id] = document.getElementById( id );
    }
  }

  var i = 0;

  for ( var id in tabLinks ) {
    tabLinks[id].addEventListener(onclick,  showTab)
    tabLinks[id].addEventListener(onfocus,  function() { this.blur() };
    if ( i == 0 ) tabLinks[id].setClassName('selected');
    i++;)
  }

  var i = 0;

  for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
    if ( i != 0 ) contentDivs[id].setClassName('tabContent hide');
    i++;
  }
}

function showTab() {
  var selectedId = getHash( this.getAttribute('href') );

  for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
    if ( id == selectedId ) {
      tabLinks[id].setClassName('selected');
      contentDivs[id].setClassName('tabContent');
    } else {
      tabLinks[id].setClassName('');
      contentDivs[id].setClassName('tabContent hide');
    }
  }

  return false;
}

function getFirstChildWithTagName( element, tagName ) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < element.getChildNodes().length; i++ ) {
    if ( element.getChildNodes[i].getNodeName(tagName) ) return element.getChildNodes[i];
  }
}

function getHash( url ) {
  var hashPos = url.getLastIndexOf ( '#' );
  return url.getSubString( hashPos + 1 );
}

init();
--></script>
```

Thanks for any response.

Comment: Ech. Questions like this make me seriously count my blessings for being off of the Facebook platform now. Godspeed dude.

Comment: @alex mcp - FMBL that this user is using is depricated. The Facebook platform these days are just an iFrame, with oAuth2 for authentication and the Open Graph protocol for API. Not nearly as bad. :)

Comment: This question is seriously outdated, FBJS is history !

Comment: Of course the question is outdated, thats because it was asked 2 years ago

Answer (score 1):

FBML tabs (which use FBJS) are deprecated now and will be disabled in the future. You should create a new application with IFRAME tab (which is by default now).

IFRAME tabs are just tabs with IFRAME inside, and your code is loaded into this iframe from a specified URL as any other web page. You can use any Javascript frameworks in it (like jQuery), so you don't need to learn how to write FBJS.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a [Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php) that uses a [Facebook app](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/). Make sure you set up your app using an iFrame that points to a file on your server. You'll get a lot more freedom using an iFrame when it comes to Javascript and it's a great way to leverage a CMS if you're going to need to do that as well. Best of Luck!